# Access fluidpage configuration in template

Tags: typo3, fedext

I'm trying to access fluid page configuration inside a template.

In detail: I added a selectfield to my page layout

```
            <flux:flexform.field.select name="pageIcon" items="{
                0: {0: '{f:translate(key: \'pageIconNone\')}', 1: ''},
                1: {0: '{f:translate(key: \'pageIconFacebook\')}', 1: 'fa-facebook-square'},
                2: {0: '{f:translate(key: \'pageIconFlickr\')}', 1: 'fa-flickr'},
                3: {0: '{f:translate(key: \'pageIconGooglePlus\')}', 1: 'fa-google-plus-square'}
            }"/>
```

So far so good. Now I render a menu an want to access this field pageIcon

```
    <v:page.menu.directory pages="{settings.pid.socialMenu}" useShortcutData="TRUE" classFirst="first" classLast="last">
            <f:for each="{menu}" as="mainPage" iteration="iteration">
                <a href="{mainPage.link}" class="{mainPage.class}"><i class="fa {mainPage.pageIcon} fa-2x"></i><b>{mainPage.title}</b></a>
            </f:for>
    </v:page.menu.directory>
```

But this does not work. After some debugging I noticed, that this configuration seems to be stored in **tx_fed_page_flexform** which holds an XML array.

How can I access the XML values inside my fluid template?

Markus

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way:

https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/flux/master/Form/DataViewHelper.html

`<flux:flexform.data table="pages" field="tx_fed_page_flexform" uid="{pageUid}" as="pageData">
    <a href="#">{pageData.pageIcon}</a>
</flux:flexform.data>`

The reason for not extracting this data always, is simply for performance. There is another way which you may not be aware of:

`<flux:flexform.field.select name="pages.pageIcon" items="{...}" />`

If you name your field thusly (the `pages.` prefix is the key since we are using the `pages` DB table) your value will be saved into a field in the record itself (a field you must then add in the SQL schema / TCA, and enable value sliding in the rootline if you desire it). If a field with this prefix is saved, Flux will insert its value directly into the pages record which means you can immediately access it using for example `{pageVariable.icon}` without the need for the `flux:flexform.data` ViewHelper.

#### UPDATE

For more recent version of Flux, try:

`<flux:form.data table="pages" field="tx_fed_page_flexform" uid="{pageUid}" as="pageData">
    <a href="#">{pageData.pageIcon}</a>
</flux:form.data>`

Comment: Hi Claus, thank you. As usual a very helpful answer!

Comment: In the new version, it is now flus:form.data dans flux:field.select.

Comment: @ClausDue Is the part with the `pages.` prefix still valid for recent fluidpages versions?

Comment: Should work for any table, yes. The field you map to must have valid TCA.