# Access tx_fed_page_flexform in fluidtemplate

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

This question is related to [Access fluidpage configuration in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489001/access-fluidpage-configuration-in-template).

I try the same as in the question above. But as `flux:flexform`is outdated and replaced with `flux:form` there may be some changes I'm not aware of.

With the following code I try to access the flex:form.fields from the menu-items:

```
<v:page.menu levels="1" as="sections">

        <ul class="main-navi">
            <f:for each="{sections}" as="section" iteration="iteration">

            <f:debug>{section}</f:debug>
            <flux:form.data table="pages" field="tx_fed_page_flexform" uid="{section.uid}" as="sectionData" />
            <f:debug>{sectionData}</f:debug>
                <li {f:if(condition: section.active, then: ' class="active"')}>
                    <f:link.page pageUid="{section.uid}" title="{section.linktext}">{ section.title}</f:link.page>
                    <div class="testmenu"></div>
                </li>
            </f:for>
        </ul>

</v:page.menu>
```

In the Debug of the section (`<f:debug>{section}</f:debug>`) I see the value of tx_fed_page_flexform:

```
tx_fed_page_flexform => '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="
      ;yes" ?> <T3FlexForms> <data> <sheet inde
      x="options"> <language index="lDEF">
      ; <field index="text"> &
      lt;value index="vDEF">test1234</value> &l
      t;/field> </language> </sheet> </d
      ata> </T3FlexForms>' (336 chars)
```

The value I search is `test1234`.

But when I debug the sectionData (`<f:debug>{sectionData}</f:debug>`) I just get a `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. To set sectionData use `v:variable.set`. the `as` in `flux:form.data` seems not to work.

```
<v:variable.set name="sectionData" value="{flux:form.data(table:'pages', field:'tx_fed_page_flexform', uid:'{section.uid}')}" />
```